# What can I do to track stolen funds?

Tags: mtgox

I have mtgox account, and once I changed my android software i forgot to link another google authenticator, so to access mtgox I had to unlink it of OTP.That wwas two weeks ago
Last week, i still didn't linked new OTP, and I had my BTC funds stolen and widthdrawed to another account. I know that transactions canot be undone by can I do anything to find where are my BTCs?

Regards

Comment: Have you looked at your transaction history at MtGox?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to know the exact date and the address that was used to take the BTC from your MtGox account, I dont think there are any way to know where they went.

And even if you could find where they are (or where you think they are) there are no way to take them back.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check transaction history at MtGox?

A key element of the Bitcoin protocol is the block chain, which is a public transaction database. This contains most all transactions made in bitcoins and also includes information such as the sending and receiving addresses. You can find historical transaction data for the past 3 months by using a block chain explorer like ABE or Blockchain.info.

As the person before me stated even if you could find where they are there is no way to take them back.